# CAPL: Why am I not receiving the data bytes of a CAN message in CAPL?

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I have an ECU sending a CAN message with 2 bytes of data. I want to take those 2 data bytes in CAPL and put them into 2 environment variables. I am developing a canoe simulation and I want to use those 2 environment variables to display their value in a panel.

I am seeing the CAN message with the data bytes on trace being received correctly, but when I try using those data bytes in CAPL, they are 0.

I have the following code:

```
message CAN1.SWversion  SWversion;

on message SWversion
{
  putValue(ev_MainSW, SWversion.MainSW);
  putValue(ev_SecSW, SWversion.SecSW);
}
```

SWversion.MainSW is byte(0), SWversion.SecSW is byte(1). I see their values on trace, but in CAPL they are 0.

Any hints as to why?

[Here's my trace window with the data bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmxz2.png)

[Here's my message & signals definition in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnF5c.png)

[Here's one of my variable definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLoBm.png)

Comment: We cannot see your trace window, the signal definition, the environment variable definition, ...

Comment: Hi, @M.Spiller. I have added your suggestions to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Your environment variable has a value range from 0x0 to 0x0. Have you tried to print out the received values in CAPL?

Comment: All of my variables have that value range and it was never a problem to put bigger values in them. But the variables are not the problem, I have printed the received values (the CAN message's bytes) in CAPL and those are 0. The values are 0 before being set in the environment variables.

Comment: The code I pasted in the question is everything I have in CAPL for that message, but somehow I think I need to invoke some king of getData() method before using the values of the signals and putting them in the variables. Am I on the right track?

Comment: What is that first line in your CAPL code? This code will not compile. Is that a global variable? Are you writing to that variable somewhere? Why are you accessing that variable in your message handler instead of the received message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
message CAN1.SWversion  SWversion;

on message SWversion
{
  putValue(ev_MainSW, SWversion.MainSW);
  putValue(ev_SecSW, SWversion.SecSW);
}
```

needed to be changed to

```
message CAN1.SWversion  SWversion;

on message SWversion
{
  putValue(ev_MainSW, this.byte(0));
  putValue(ev_SecSW, this.byte(1);
}
```

Apparently, you cannot use predefined signals to access the data in a CAN message in CAPL.

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler it seems that you should access the received message, not a global (obviously uninitialized) variable:

```
on message CAN1.SWversion
{
  putValue(ev_MainSW, this.MainSW);
  putValue(ev_SecSW, this.SecSW);
}
```